# Python MySQL returning table data - only shows everything on one line

Tags: python, mysql, sql, return

Basically,I'm returning data from a table :

```
 >mysql> SELECT x,y FROM xandy;  
 >+------+------+  
>| x    | y    |  
>+------+------+  
>|    5 |    2 |   
>|    4 |    6 |  
>|    7 |    6 |  
>|    4 |    6 |  
>|    8 |    7 |  
>|    4 |    6 |  
>|   11 |   33 |  
>|   33 |   22 |  
>+------+------+  
>8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

(sorry for poor formatting)

```
    def fetch():

      try:
       db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost",user="root",passwd="****",db="logger")

       cursor=db.cursor()

       SQLString = "SELECT x,y FROM xandy;"
       cursor.execute(SQLString)
       rows=cursor.fetchall()

       return rows
       db.close()
```

However when I get the returned value I get it all on one line in the format of :

> ((5.0, 2.0), (4.0, 6.0), (7.0, 6.0), (4.0, 6.0), (8.0, 7.0), (4.0, 6.0), (11.0, 33.0), (33.0, 22.0), (6.0, 4.0))

Is there a way to display it in a simple table form i.e two columns with x and y? ( p.s I will be using gnuplot after this step)

Comment: On a side note: your `db.close()` is never reached.

Answer (score 0):

That data looks good in that it's a tuple of tuples and you could index it like a table.

i.e. You could get the element in row m and column n with

```
rows[m][n]
```

Are you just looking to print it out in 2 columns?

```
for x, y in rows:
    print("{0}, {1}".format(x,y))
```

Comment: I'm only able to return "5.0, 2.0" and not the rest ? Any other suggestions?

Comment: When you say you're only able to return "5.0, 2.0" what do you mean by that? Are you doing "rows = cursor.fetchall()" and then "return rows"? I'm confused as to whether you are having trouble viewing the data or returning it. The returned object you mentioned in the question has all the data in it. So it's just a question of what format you'd like that data to be in.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a function called `fetch` similar to yours above, you might use it like this:

```
rows = fetch()
print '\n'.join(' '.join(str(x) for x in row) for row in rows)
```